# Docker Error: Could not find or load Main class Main.Main

Tags: java, linux, docker, jar, .class-file

I have coded this Dockerfile that makes a runnable jar out of a project and it also builds but when i try to run it, it says "Error: Could not find or load Main class Main.Main"

Dockerfile:

```
RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64  java-1.8.0-openjdk- 
devel.x86_64 && yum clean all

COPY resources /home/resources
COPY elk_casino_server /home/elk_casino_server
RUN /usr/bin/javac /home/elk_casino_server/src/Main/Main.java
RUN jar vcmf /home/elk_casino_server/src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
/home/elk_casino_server/src/server.jar
/home/elk_casino_server/src/Main/Main.class 
/home/elk_casino_server/src/config.properties
CMD ["java","-jar","/home/elk_casino_server/src/server.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker `COPY` command accepts **path** as a second parameter. Try changing your `Dockerfile`

**Dockerfile**

```
...
COPY resources /home/
COPY elk_casino_server /home/
...
```

Comment: now it just saves the content of the resources and elk_casino_server folder into /home but now cant even build because paths are not the same